# How to properly access c++/CLI initonly TimeSpan field?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, .net-4.0, c++-cli

The following code compiles with warning and intellisense error:

```
ref class Test {
    initonly static TimeSpan Delay = TimeSpan(1,1,1); 

    Test() {
        long long ticks = Delay.Ticks; // << problem
    }
};
```

The problems are:

- warning C4395: 'System::TimeSpan::Ticks::get' : member function will
  be invoked on a copy of the initonly data member 'Test::Delay'
- IntelliSense: taking the address of an initonly field is not allowed

How to access Ticks properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, that's pretty major fail-whale.  The warning is accurate, the compiler doesn't know enough about the TimeSpan::Tick property getter.  It cannot ensure that the getter doesn't do anything that might alter the value of the struct and thereby invalidates the *initonly* contract.  It solves it by making a copy of the struct and warns about it since this is a possible perf issue.  That's a bit heavy-handed, other managed compilers make the copy without saying anything about it.  I'd just plunk a `#pragma warning(disable:4395)` ahead of it so the warning is suppressed.

The IntelliSense error only appears when I try this in VS2012.  That's a bug.  You can report it at connect.microsoft.com.

Given the misery and that this appears to be a private class member, I'd just drop *initonly* to get ahead.  If that's not desirable then you can wrap the field with a property, intentionally creating the copy, and thus get rid of both problems, like this:

```
ref class Test {
    initonly static TimeSpan _delay = TimeSpan(1,1,1); 
    static property TimeSpan Delay { 
        TimeSpan get() { return _delay; }
    }

    Test() {
        long long ticks = Delay.Ticks;
    }
};
```

The jitter optimizer will get rid of it so don't worry about overhead.

Comment: This warning is still present in VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hans Passant for his explanation, I understand the context much better now

I have just come across the same problem.

My solution was

- replace the 'initonly' by 'const'
- When accessing, just cast the const away, and there will not be any errors/warnings left

Maybe this is not 'state of the art' coding but it works fine, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137406/c-cli-access-structure-member/52148534#52148534)
(VisualStudio2017 does still expose this behaviour/problem)