# C++/CLI -- Access Structure Member

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I am trying to access a .NET structure member but compilation fails even for this simple example:

.h:

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
namespace MyNamespace{
  public ref class MyClass{
    public:
      MyClass();
      static const System::Drawing::Size MinimumSize = System::Drawing::Size(20,20);
  }
}
```

.cpp:

```
#include "MyInclude.h"
MyClass::MyClass(){
  int i = MinimumSize.Width;
  // .....
}
```

The statement which assigns the MinimumSize.Width to the local variable i fails to compile:

- "No instance of function "System::Drawing::Size::Width::get()" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match) object type is const System::Drawing::Size

The assignment compiles without error when I remove the "const" in the declaration but I want to keep the value public and read-only.

Can somebody give me a hint how to specify that?

Comment: Using C++/CLI for WindowsForms is stupid. Use C++/cx or C#.

Comment: The "type qualifiers" it is complaining about is the `const`.  The Width property getter is not const, none of the .NET framework methods are const functions.  A basic impedance mismatch between C++ and the .NET virtual machine.  The proper keyword is `initonly`.  That however triggers a new diagnostic in this specific case, a warning this time.  The subject of [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831773/how-to-properly-access-c-cli-initonly-timespan-field).

Comment: @Swordfish: There is a good reason for me to do it in C++/CLI. I am writing a DLL which should behave as a standard DLL to the C# application **and** make use of DirrectWrite/DirectX interfaces.
Still stupid? You may want to consider again.

Comment: Yes, still stupid. There are libraries like SharpDX for a reason.

Comment: @Swordfish: Take it your way. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried it: 'initonly' produces **two** messages when I attempt to allocate MinimumSize.Width to 'i':

- Warning C4395 'System::Drawing::Size::Width::get': member function will be invoked on a copy of the initonly data member 'MBcppLibrary::DrForm::MinimumSize' ([as mentioned by 
  Dmitry Nogin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831773/how-to-properly-access-c-cli-initonly-timespan-field) / Hans Passant)

plus the message

- "taking the address of an initonly field is not allowed"

I am using this solution:

1. Just leave the 'static const' declaration
2. Apply a type cast to the assignment statement

```js
int i = (( System::Drawing::Size)MinimumSize).Width;
```

This cast gets rid of the 'const', compiles without any error/warning and executes as expected. Or is this a bit too much brut force?

Regards PaulTheHacker

Comment: Shame on me! Sorry -- a typecast is so simple that I did not even think about it.
But it works fine. Thank you.