# Readonly vs static readonly clarification

Tags: c#

I've run into an interesting situation I am trying to understand. I have a `readonly` struct field in my class. This means that when I reference it, it references a copy and not the actual one, so when I call a `change` method, it will be working with a copy, and the original will remain unchanged.

That is not what I am observing. I only see the expected behavior with a static field. I expected the behavior for both types.

```
private struct junk
{
    public int i;

    public void change()
    {
        i += 1;
    }
}

private readonly junk jk;
private static readonly junk jk2;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    jk.change();
    //jk.i is now 1, why? Shouldn't it be changing a copy and not the original jk?
    jk2.change();
    //jk2.i is 0
}
```

Comment: Mutable value types - just say **no**.

Comment: please get rid of the irrelevant call to `InitializeComponent()` and insert code that prints the values of `jk.i` and `jk2.i` and show us what it prints.  We do not care to read what you think the values are, we want to see what the values are.

Comment: (And we also want to see what makes you think the values are what you claim they are.)

Comment: A warning would have been nice, but the C# compiler does not have the plumbing that can ensure that change() has an observable side-effect.  A counter-example is the C++/CLI compiler, [it always assumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832116/17034) and that doesn't make programmers happy either.  Add `static Form1()` to see that it is allowed to mutate the jk2 value.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a readonly struct field in my class. This means that when I reference it, it references a copy and not the actual one, so when I call a change method, it will be working with a copy, and the original will remain unchanged.

That's not at all what the `readonly` modifier does. The `readonly` modifier prevents you from assigning a new value to `jk` anywhere but in a constructor. Then, the `static` modifier allows you to reuse that value independently of the instance of `Form1` you are working with.
That said, neither `readonly` nor `static` is making the weird behavior you are describing because that exact behavior cannot be reproduced with the code you've posted.

Look at a simpler example in a Console application (which you can try [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YKiCaM)):

```
public class Program
{
    private readonly junk jk;
    private static readonly junk jk2;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.jk.change();
        Console.WriteLine(program.jk.i); // prints 0

        jk2.change();
        Console.WriteLine(jk2.i); // prints 0
    }
}

public struct junk
{
    public int i;
    public void change()
    {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Then, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever commented, try to avoid mutable `struct`s as much as you can.